# how to solve ** relation "dual" does not exist ** problem in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to convert Oracle to PostgreSQL. While converting I'm getting error like
*relation "dual" does not exist* .

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE*(POWER(10,6)) FROM DUAL'
```

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: remove `from dual` - a FROM clause is not required in Postgres. Obviously you need to replace `dbms_random.value()` with the appropriate Postgres function. And using dynamic SQL seems completely pointless here

Answer (score 0):

Dual is a dummy table specific for oracle. In PostgreSQL you can either just use

```
SELECT random()*power( 10, 6 );
```

or create your own `dual` table if you want to keep the dual. (and insert 1 row in it)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view named dual like:

```
CREATE VIEW public.dual AS SELECT 'X'::varchar AS dummy;
```

REF: https://pgpedia.info/d/dual-dummy-table.html